# How to setup laravel mix for dynamic import for project in subdirectory

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

My project is located at subdir: http://localhost/my-project (for example), so the public url is http://localhost/my-project/public
I'm trying to make use of webpack's dynamic import, but when it tries to import chunk, it looks for it at domain's root like so: http://localhost/js/chunks/0.js, which results to 404 error

I've tried to set mix publicPath option, but it didn't help. And I've also set up `<base>` html tag to point to my public folder, but it didn't helped too.

Here is my webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');

mix.setPublicPath('public/');

mix
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
        ],

        output: {
            chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].js'
        }
    })
    .options({
        extractVueStyles: true
    })
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found solution by myself. Looks like setting webpack publicPath to empty string combined with `<base href="{{ url('/') }}/">`worked just as i need. (I also expect that bundled project will be independent of being placed either in domain's root or in subdirectory)

```
mix
    .webpackConfig({
        output: {
            chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].js',
            publicPath: ''
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for taking effort to answer your question!